# The result of proposition with paradox

Tags: proof-verification, paradoxes

I'am not sure this question fits with this site.
If not, I will delete it.

I just wonder a proposition as follows:

**A statement *'S'* is true => paradox**

So.. what's the reulst?  The ***'S'*** is true, false or undecidable?

Maybe it's undecidable. Why? I thought ***'S'*** should be false.

Comment: If you accept the law of excluded middle, then you can conclude that if $S$ being true implies a paradox, then $S$ is false. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_excluded_middle

Comment: Thank you for answer. I got confused it.